# Efficiently find nested PHP array element based on attribute value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Suppose a PHP array, when cast to JSON, has the following format:

```
[{
    "key": "width",
    "value": "1200",
    "label": "Width (mm)",
    "choice": ""
},
{
    "key": "height",
    "value": "900",
    "label": "Height (mm)",
    "choice": ""
},
{
    "key": "material",
    "value": "paper",
    "label": "Material",
    "choice": "Paper"
}]
```

(This is a shortened version of the original, which can have many more elements)

Let's suppose I want to efficiently find what material is used. In other words, I want to search for a nested array that has for `key` the value `material`, and I want to return the `value` which would be `paper`.

I know this can be done by using a foreach/while loop, but PHP is rich with compiled array functions that I'm not very familiar with. What's the best function to use here?

---

**UPDATE: What I've tried so far**

Here's two things I've tried so far:

Attempt #1:

```
$json = '[{"key":"width","value":"1200","label":"Width (mm)","choice":""},{"key":"height","value":"900","label":"Height (mm)","choice":""},{"key":"material","value":"paper","label":"Material","choice":"Paper"}]';
$array = json_encode($json, true);
$material = '';
foreach($array as $nestedArray) {
  if($nestedArray['key'] = 'material') {
    $material = $nestedArray['value'];
  }
}
```

Attempt #2:

```
$json = '[{"key":"width","value":"1200","label":"Width (mm)","choice":""},{"key":"height","value":"900","label":"Height (mm)","choice":""},{"key":"material","value":"paper","label":"Material","choice":"Paper"}]';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$filteredArray = array_filter($array, function($array) {
    return ($array['key'] == 'material');
});
$arr = array_pop($filteredArray)['value'];
```

---

Both produce the right value, but #1 is messy, and #2 may not be the best use of PHPs array functions.

Comment: Is it a json text string?

Comment: Efficient as in microoptimize, or efficient as in memory usage, or efficient as in code written?

Comment: @Andreas it originally exists as a JSON text string, correct

Comment: @mario, efficient as in not loop through 100 nested arrays looking at each one, and instead using a function like `array_filter()`, which doesn't quite fit the bill

Comment: What you have tried so far? Can  you please post your inputs

Comment: @NarendrasinghSisodia updated with two things I've tried so far, both work, but I'm worried I'm using only the functions I know, and that there may be some other function I'm not familiar with that is well suited to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends on what you want to do** in addition to "finding the value". And what you have.

`array_filter` is simple, but it will loop through the whole array.

`array_search` on a reduced set looks faster, but it needs to make a copy of the source array, so it's actually *slower* than `array_filter` (not by much).

The `foreach` solution you tried first will not create extra arrays and it allows you to break on a find:

```
foreach($array as $nestedArray) {
    if ($nestedArray['key'] == 'material') {
        $material = $nestedArray['value'];
        break; // <--- found!
    }
}
```

So on short arrays I'd go with the accepted solution using `array_column`, or if you're sure that the material is there, there is this `array_column` tweak:

```
// Transform the records into keypairs
$keypairs = array_column($records, 'value', 'key');
```

Now keypairs is [ width => 900, material => paper, ... ], so:

```
$material = $keypairs['material'];
```

I'd add a `array_key_exists` just to be sure. This saves the `array_search` (not that great an advantage, but you might have a use for the keypair object).

If you need exactly that one value and nothing else, performance is at a premium, and the array is large, I'd not throw out the idea of looking for '"material":"' inside the JSON as a string with `strpos`, even if it's a code smell.

Comment: Across 10000 iterations, this function is more efficient, and returning the keypairs could come in handy. I'm changing the accepted answer to this one, thanks @LSemi

Answer (score 1):

If it's a json text as you stated in comments my advice is a regex match.

This will find "key material" and "value" and match the value of value.
It works on the small sample, but you have to try it on a larger string.

https://regex101.com/r/CSTLUL/1

```
$re = '/key\": \"material\",.*?\"value\": \"(.*?)\",/s';
$str = '{
"key": "width",
"value": "1200",
"label": "Width (mm)",
"choice": ""
},
{
"key": "height",
"value": "900",
"label": "Height (mm)",
"choice": ""
},
{
"key": "material",
"value": "paper",
"label": "Material",
"choice": "Paper"
}]';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Andreas, but I prefer Jigar's answer which uses the PHP array functions

Comment: Sure. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) so no need to use loop

**Working Demo**: https://eval.in/865566

```
$data = '[{
    "key": "width",
    "value": "1200",
    "label": "Width (mm)",
    "choice": ""
},
{
    "key": "height",
    "value": "900",
    "label": "Height (mm)",
    "choice": ""
},
{
    "key": "material",
    "value": "paper",
    "label": "Material",
    "choice": "Paper"
}]';
$data = json_decode($data,True);


$key = array_search('material', array_column($data, 'key')); // get key of array
echo $data[$key]['value'];
```

Output

```
paper
```

Comment: Brilliant, exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. I'd just stumbled upon the array_search/array_column trick, but was having trouble getting it working properly.

Comment: Thanks, glad to help you :)