# How can i extract data from multi dimentional array

Tags: php

I have the following code how can i extract `[real]` value if `[name] => Y Downtime Switch`

```
[inputs] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => X Downtime Switch
                    [raw] => 10
                    [real] => 0.01
                    [unit] => V
                    [count] => 0
                    [maxval] => 10
                    [minval] => 0
                    [decimals] => 2
                    [alarm] => A---
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Y Downtime Switch
                    [raw] => 9197
                    [real] => 9.2
                    [unit] => V
                    [count] => 0
                    [maxval] => 10
                    [minval] => 0
                    [decimals] => 2
                    [alarm] => ----
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Z Run PR
                    [raw] => 9187
                    [real] => 9187
                    [unit] => mV
                    [count] => 0
                    [maxval] => 10000
                    [minval] => 0
                    [decimals] => 0
                    [alarm] => ----
                    )
)
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Where is your code? How do you expect us to help with it, if you keep it secret?

Comment: What secrete? i didn't hide anything i just post what i fell is enough.

Comment: You did not post the code you implemented yourself to solve this task...

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336832/efficiently-find-nested-php-array-element-based-on-attribute-value, which I asked two months ago. The only difference is that I started with a JSON string and immediately decoded it into this array format. See the accepted answer there, as it addresses the issue from the array input perspective.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of helping itself:

```
<?php
$data = [
    [
        'name' => "X Downtime Switch",
        'real' => 0.01,
    ],
    [
        'name' => "Y Downtime Switch",
        'real' => 9.2
    ],
    [
        'name' => "Z Run PR",
        'real' => 9187
    ]
];
$output = null;
array_walk($data, function($entry) use (&$output) {
    if ($entry['name'] == "Y Downtime Switch") {
        $output = $entry['real'];
    }
} );
var_dump($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
float(9.2)
```

However I really recommend to you to read a bit about how this place works:

We are not here to do your work for you. We are here to help you with specific issues you run into while trying to solve your tasks yourself. That means you are expected to write your own code.